# unable to install autossh on Raspberry PI OS Lite (32-bit) 06-sept-2022 release

Tags: software-installation, raspberry-pi-os

i am unable to install autossh on a fresh installation of Raspberry PI OS with the latest bits.
for some reason this seems to go to a server in the Philippines which probably is incorrect.
`"http://mirror.rise.ph/raspbian/raspbian bullseye/main armhf autossh armhf 1.4g-1"` and fails with a 404.

--fix-missing switch makes no difference

is there a way to change this to another country ? or solve this in another way ??

Comment: DO NOT post pictures of text post TEXT!

Comment: DO NOT use `apt-get` which is not designed for interactive use - use `apt`